# Can docker be instructed to not download images if they do not exist locally?

Tags: docker

Is there a way to ensure that docker does not automatically attempt to download a container image if it doesn't exist locally? That is, a way to configure the docker daemon to avoid looking for `FOO` remotely if someone runs `docker run FOO` locally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Update:

Docker released this feature on version [20.10.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/#20100) *(2020-12-14)*:

> Client:
>
> - Add `--pull=missing|always|never` to `run` and `create` commands [docker/cli#1498](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/2646)

---

### Old:

Currently, there is no way to do that, but there is an open Pull Request ([#1498](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1498)) to add this feature:

> • This PR adds a new `--pull` flag to `docker run` and `docker create`,
> following the proposal in [moby/moby#34394](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34394).
>
> • Per this proposal, the flag is tristate:
>
> 1. --pull=missing (this is the current behaviour and will be the default.)
> 2. --pull=never
> 3. --pull=always
>
> • [...] pull the image if it
> does not exist at all locally (`--pull=missing`), always try and update
> the image (`--pull=always`), or **never try and update the image, only using
> images that already exist on the local machine (`--pull=never`)**

Stay tuned to see when the merge will be accepted, and in which version the feature will be included.

Comment: Thanks! While waiting, people in my position can first test to see if the image is available locally by running `docker image inspect IMAGE:TAG` which will exit with success if the image is available locally, but exits with a failure status code otherwise.

Comment: @TendersMcChiken the feature was released on version 20.10.0 :)